# Jquery to send data from one field to another field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to push data from one field to another field only if there is data in the field. If there is data in Requeter_UserName_COAS, then I want that data to be pushed to the Requester_UserName field. Here is my code for the field set (textfield) any suggestions to help the onchange function?

```
    $form['fieldform']['coas']['Requester_UserName_COAS'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Faculty Name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array( 'placeholder' => "Alex Jones",
         'required' => "required",
            ),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="forms-jd">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

    'onchange' => "if($(this).val() = True)  {this.form.elements['Requester_UserName'].value = 'Requester_UserName_COAS';}",
```

Comment: Well, `if (thing = True)` has two issues.  First, `=` is assignment, and will always be true.  You need to use `==` or `===` for comparison.  Secondly, where is `True` defined?

Comment: Yea corrected the first issue. The second issue a little more tricky. It is not defined anywhere. What I am trying to do is this: If this field has data I want that data replicated in the Requester_UserName field which is hidden and pushed out in the array. If that makes sense.

Comment: So the conditional is trying to check if the value is not blank?

Comment: That would be correct

Comment: Then you do not need the equality in the if.  A non-blank string is truthy in javascript

Comment: This may shed a little more light on the issue. I have a drop down box on this form that selects one of 4 colleges. If the COAS college is selected it display those fields that are COAS related including the UserName field. The other 3 Colleges also have the UserName field. I am sending the output to another form will only accept the Requester_UserName field name. This is why I am trying to put a onchange here. I have tried 'onchange' => "$(this).val ()= ['Requester_UserName'].value;",
It ends up giving me an error 500 error.

Comment: Sorry I am really  a beginner here.